# udunits2 package installation in Docker image

Tags: installation, docker, packages, r

I'm trying to install the R package udunits2/units in a Docker image

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook:abdb27a6dfbb

USER root

RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install -y libudunits2-dev
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('udunits2', configure.args=c('--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include'), repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org/')"
```

While it seems that libudunits-2.0 is installed, the installation process of udunits2 in R can't seem to use it.

```
checking udunits2.h usability... no
checking udunits2.h presence... yes
checking for udunits2.h... no
checking for ut_read_xml in -ludunits2... no
-----Error: libudunits2.a not found-----
     If the udunits2 library is installed in a non-standard location,
     use --configure-args='--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/local/lib' for example,
     or --configure-args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2'
     replacing paths with appropriate values for your installation.
     You can alternatively use the UDUNITS2_INCLUDE and UDUNITS2_LIB
     environment variables.
     If udunits2 is not installed, please install it.
     It is required for this package.
```

I confirmed that the files are indeed where I've defined:

```
Step 5/8 : RUN find /usr -name libudunits2.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudunits2.so
Step 6/8 : RUN find /usr -name libudunits2.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudunits2.a
Step 7/8 : RUN find /usr -name udunits2.h
/usr/include/udunits2.h
```

I've tried several different combinations of adding flags to tell where the installation should be (according to the threads below), or installing the non dev version, and sometimes the error message looks a little different:

```
configure: error: in `/tmp/RtmpiIvCWu/R.INSTALLbd0423c2d28/units':
configure: error: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Configuration failed because libudunits2.so was not found. Try installing:
    * deb: libudunits2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, ...)
    * rpm: udunits2-devel (Fedora, EPEL, ...)
    * brew: udunits (OSX)
  If udunits2 is already installed in a non-standard location, use:
    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/local/lib'
  if the library was not found, and/or:
    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2'
  if the header was not found, replacing paths with appropriate values.
  You can alternatively set UDUNITS2_INCLUDE and UDUNITS2_LIBS manually.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Others have had this problem too, but none of those so far were installing into a Docker:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955352/udunits2-h-not-found-when-installing-units-r-package

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059517/how-install-r-package-udunits2-in-ubuntu

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362201/udunits2-r-install-udunits2-h-not-found

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287164/install-udunits2-package-for-r3-3

Any ideas? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Solved!  We'll post the possible solutions shortly!

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is a summary of a workaround proposed by the author of the udunits2 package Hiebert (https://superuser.com/users/1052048/hiebert), who was unable to post his solution due to some overactive spam filters here...  So all the credit goes to him, thanks very much for your help, Hiebert!

I started with a docker image provided by jupyternotebooks (jupyter/datascience-notebook:abdb27a6dfbb).  It happens that this image has R installed through Anaconda, and in particular, anaconda has replace the normal gcc compiler with its own compiler

```
checking for gcc... x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc
```

For some reason, the anaconda compiler refuses to compile the package.  But, the normal gcc compiler will work just fine.  So one solution is to change the change the compiler (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616983/building-r-packages-using-alternate-gcc)

So, while the solution kind of "feels wrong", that's exactly what I did.  I copied the Makeconf file from the image (/opt/conda/lib/R/etc/Makeconf), changed line 15 to specify gcc as the c compiler.

```
root@4db3ae045abb:/opt/conda/lib/R/etc# diff Makeconf.old Makeconf
15c15
< CC = x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc
---
> CC = gcc
```

Then when building my docker image, I made a backup of the original Makeconf file, copied mine into the directory, installed the package, and then restored the original Makeconf file:

```
RUN mv /opt/conda/lib/R/etc/Makeconf /opt/conda/lib/R/etc/Makeconf.old
COPY Makeconf /opt/conda/lib/R/etc/Makeconf
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('udunits2', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org/')"
RUN mv /opt/conda/lib/R/etc/Makeconf.old /opt/conda/lib/R/etc/Makeconf
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this in the command line, but I'm a noobie ;)

Other alternatives suggested by Hiebert:

1. Install and use the system R from apt, which will install udunits2
   out of the box.  (I didn't do this, because I thought it complicate things with jupyternotebook, but I didn't check...)
2. Use a different Docker base image, for example the official r-base
   Docker image, which will also install udunits2 out of the box.  (I
   also didn't try this, as I wanted jupyter notebook)

There you have it!  Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using datascience-notebook, conda installation can be used and might be the easiest way. Run
`conda install -c conda-forge udunits2`.

See this site https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/udunits2 for other options. You can also search other r packages from this site.
If you are stacked with cmake or gcc problems, conda installation method would be a nice solution.

Comment: Are you associated with this site